# Prey predator excercice

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the 2-dimensional system of non-linear ODEs, semplified  instance of a predator-prey population model

$\dot x=\alpha x (1-x)-xy$

$\dot y = y(x-y)-\beta y$

with $\alpha = 1 ,\beta = 1/2$

Why does $x(0) > 0$ and $y(0) > 0$ imply that $x(t) > 0$ and $y(t) > 0$ for all times (populations remain positive)?

Could you give me at least a cue for this point?
For all equilibrium points of saddle type, compute the invariant subspaces $E^s$ and $E^u$ of their linearization.

Comment: Observe that $\dot{x}=0$ for $x=0$ and $\dot{y}=0$ for $y=0$.

Comment: @CTNT I'll add only "don't forget about existence and uniqueness theorem" :)

Comment: @Evgeny Indeed!

Comment: I tried that way, I found the solution supposing first $\dot x=0, y_0>0$ then the opposite $y'=0, x_0>0$, and I tried to find the maximal solution, but I am stuck. Any help?